# Static library integration in Swift Application: RSA SecurID SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, static-libraries

I'm trying to integrate [RSA SecurID](https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-64795) in my existing iOS Application.

It doesn't seem to be a straightforward way of achieving this task.

Here is what i've tried so far:

The files included in the zip downloaded are the following:

[image]

1. Add the files inside *inc* folder to my project as well as the *libSecurIDLib.a* .

[image]

[image]

2. Check in build phases if the library is linked in binary .

[image]

3. Check in build settings if the library path is correct .

[image]

4. Clean and Build APP and keep getting these ugly and counterintuitive errors.

[image]

Anyone have any thoughts on why i'm having this problem.

It has anything to do with the headers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added the other dependencies that are listed on page 38 of the [Developer's Guide](https://community.rsa.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/85572-102-1-177997/RSASecurIDiOSSDK240_devguide.pdf#page38).

Specifically these errors are caused because you haven't added `libxml2`, but you also need `libsqlite3` and the System configuration framework.

Comment: Thank you so much @Paulw11 , i completely skipped this part of the documentation.